# wild card for entry id mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have a blog and some of my entries are set to "members", but I want to set them to "everyone".  I originally thought it was only a few entries and so I thought to change them manually using PhpMyAdmin, but quickly realized I had more than I thought.

When using PhpMyAdmin I noticed when making the change manually (point and click) this was the command it was using (see below).  I'd like to repeat this but for ***ALL*** entries.

Is there a wild card I can use for the ***entry_id*** value?

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`blog_entry` 
SET `allow_view_entry` = 'everyone' 
WHERE `blog_entry`.`entry_id` = 4624;
```

Comment: If you want to update all rows, just remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to update ALL entries, why don't you just get rid of the condition, and execute:

```
UPDATE blog_entry SET allow_view_entry = 'everyone'
```

Otherwise, you can use a wildcard indeed, and build your statement like this:

```
UPDATE blog_entry SET allow_view_entry = 'everyone'
WHERE entry_id LIKE '%245%'
```

using the common wildcards that go with the LIKE operator.